# How PI() Value is Calculated in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please anyone can share your opinion excel how to calculate the `PI()` value.
In Execl while Calculating `=TAN(30*PI())` formula it returns `-1.07809E-14`.If i directly give the `PI()` `Value(3.141593)` it returns `1.03923E-05`.

Comment: you must do some basic research first (http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-pi-excel-54551.html)

Comment: the PI() Value which is used by excel is not what you mentioned (3.141593) as it is its rounded value. excel consider 15 decimal digits after period, so you must use `3.14159265358979`

Comment: Did you question get answered? Can you tick an answer please.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly not calculated at all, but simply stored as a constant at the maximum significance for the machine.

That's pretty certainly more than six decimal places.

Here's the first 20 digits, try putting that in: `3.14159265358979323846`

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy or otherwise of Excel's value for **π** is perhaps less of the issue here than that of Excel's TAN function. [TAN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TAN-function-08851a40-179f-4052-b789-d7f699447401) takes an argument in radians and `30*PI()` is the same angle as `2*PI()`, ie 360 degrees (a complete circle - though it might be argued that `30*PI()` is a circle after 15 complete turns). The tangent of 360<sup>o</sup> is 0 (or at least the tangent tends to 0 as the angle approaches 360<sup>o</sup>) hence whatever the accuracy chosen for **π**, any answer other than 0 is incorrect.

`-1.07809E-14` is nearer 0 than `1.03923E-05` because as has been pointed out, Excel is normally accurate to at least 14 digits and `PI()` as 3.14159265358979 is more accurate than pi as 3.141593. However -0.0000000000000107809 is nevertheless inaccurate at the 14th decimal place.

A more sensible comparison may be between the tangent of 30<sup>o</sup> with PI() and 3.141593:

`=TAN(30*PI()/180)` = 0.57735026918963
`=TAN(30*3.141593/180)` = 0.57735034616967

To 7 DP the answers are the same.

Excel evaluates 30 times PI() as 94.247779607693**8** whereas 30*3.14159265358979 as 94.247779607693**7**.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lists the following:

[MS Excel PI function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PI-function-264199d0-a3ba-46b8-975a-c4a04608989b)

### **PI function**

*Description*

> Returns the number 3.14159265358979, the mathematical constant pi, accurate to 15 digits.

you can see this by typing:

```
=pi()
```

then increasing the decimal places until you see zeros eg:

> 3.14159265358979000000